# How to sum the data in specific level after groupby or pivot_table with multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Here are my schematic diagram for my question.

After I ran "groupby" or "pivot_table" for my dataframe as below, I got an dataframe **②** with "A","B" index.  However, I doesn't need much more data. So I would like to aggregate the data in specific index level.

Then I can get the last one dataframe **③**.  b should summarise e\f index data, 1+1 = 2

This function just like the fold behavior in Excel. I checked the document(pivot_table), but "margins" this parameter is unfit for this requirement.

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Is your expectation to aggregate by 'B' only if the value is 'e' or 'f'? What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such a function, but here is a workaround:

```
df
     C
A B
a p  1
  q  1
d r  2
  s  2
b t  3
  v  3
  w  3
c x  4
  y  4

fld=["d","b","c"]
nfidx=df.index.levels[0].difference(fld)

   Index(['a'], dtype='object', name='A')


df2= df.loc[fld].groupby("A").sum()

       C
    A
    b  9
    c  8
    d  4

mi= pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.index,[np.nan]],names=["A","B"])

    MultiIndex([('b', nan),
                ('c', nan),
                ('d', nan)],
               names=['A', 'B'])

df2.index=mi

           C
    A B
    b NaN  9
    c NaN  8
    d NaN  4

pd.concat([ df.loc[nfidx],df2])

           C
    A B
    a p    1
      q    1
    b NaN  9
    c NaN  8
    d NaN  4
```